# Interfaces with required proofs, in Idris

Tags: interface, proof, idris

I've been trying to learn Idris in the past few days, following the book [Type-Driven development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris). After reading the part about equality proofs, I started to think about having an interface that *requires* some equality proofs. Let's give some examples:

```
interface ProperFunctor (f : Type -> Type) where
  fmap : (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  functorial : {phi : b -> c} -> {psi : a -> b} -> {fx : f a} ->
               fmap (phi . psi) fx = (fmap phi . fmap psi) fx
```

A possible instance of this interface would be any functor that **really** is a functor (a.k.a. that satisfies functoriality, on top of having a *type correct* `fmap`). Again, an example is worth a million words:

```
ProperFunctor List where
  fmap f [] = []
  fmap f (x :: xs) = f x :: fmap f xs

  functorial = ?functorial_rhs
```

how to fill the hole?

Providing explicit values for the implicit arguments really does help, of course, as does type inspection.

```
ProperFunctor List where
  fmap f [] = []
  fmap f (x :: xs) = f x :: fmap f xs

  functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = []) = Refl
  functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = (x :: xs)} = ?functorial_rhs_2
```

At this point, the most natural way to complete the proof seems (to me at least) to be induction on `fx`:

```
ProperFunctor List where
  fmap f [] = []
  fmap f (x :: xs) = f x :: fmap f xs

  functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = []) = Refl
  functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = (x :: xs)} =
    let indHyp = functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = xs}
    in rewrite indHyp in Refl
```

All this actually type-check properly, but a strange thing happens when I try to remove the `let` clause:

```
ProperFunctor List where
  fmap f [] = []
  fmap f (x :: xs) = f x :: fmap f xs

  functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = []) = Refl
  functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = (x :: xs)} =
    rewrite (functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = xs}) in Refl
```

Doesn't type-check anymore: I get a "Can't find implementation for ProperFunctor f", followed by an error message about a type mismatch (that I can't seem to wrap my head around):

```
Type checking ./<file>.idr
<file>.idr:17:5-54:
   |
17 |     rewrite (functorial {phi} {psi} {fx = xs}) in Refl
   |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When checking right hand side of Main.Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method functorial with expected type
        Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap c a (phi . psi) (x :: xs) =
        (Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap c b phi . Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap b a psi) (x :: xs)

Can't find implementation for ProperFunctor f

Possible cause:
        <file>.idr:17:13-46:When checking an application of function rewrite__impl:
                Type mismatch between
                        phi2 (psi3 x) :: Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap c1 b4 phi2 (Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap b4 a5 psi3 xs) =
                        phi2 (psi3 x) ::
                        Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap c1 b4 phi2 (Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap b4 a5 psi3 xs) (Type of Refl)
                and
                        (\replaced =>
                           phi2 (psi3 x) :: replaced =
                           phi2 (psi3 x) ::
                           Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap c1 b4 phi2 (Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap b4 a5 psi3 xs)) (fmap phi
                                                                                                                                                                                     (fmap psi
                                                                                                                                                                                           fx)) (Expected type)

                Specifically:
                        Type mismatch between
                                Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap c1 b2 phi3 (Main.List implementation of Main.ProperFunctor, method fmap b2 a4 psi5 xs)
                        and
                                fmap phi (fmap psi fx)
```

What is going on here? Am I using `let` the wrong way, does this happen because of how `rewrite` works, or have I totally misunderstood how to use these features? Any hint will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using Idris 1.3.2 on Arch Linux; I don't think it has anything to do with my question, but it might if this is a bug.